# MBP 13" 2017 nTB external display issues when used with 2 DELL external displays

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

I have a MBP 13" nTB 2017 which i am intending to use with 2 DELL monitors (U2414H and U2417H) as extended desktops.

However, i am facing some weird issue with the display issues shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vq6AtroJpU&feature=youtu.be).

- persistent screen blanking out and weird glitches. Screen will blank out intermittently and seemingly shift left or right across the screen (similar to when trying to switch between windows on mac)

How to replicate this issue:

- whichever monitor that is connected second will have that display issue regardless of the setup i have tried which are mentioned below
  (e.g connect monitor A then monitor B, monitor B will have that display issue and vice versa)

What i have tried:

1. Initially both monitors were connected to the usb-c ports via HDMI-usbc adapters. I figured that could be cause of the issue.
2. i got a new displayport-usbc cable for one of the monitors and gave it a try. Issue mentioned above still persists.

Anyone experienced this issue before? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution to this website. It would help if you could explain what problem you are having, as the video is quite vague and has no context. If you could edit this or potentially add in another clip showing what happens when you plug in the screens that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, the video is showing the issue i am facing. Screen will blank out intermittently and seemingly shift left or right across the screen (similar to when trying to switch between windows on mac)

Comment: Ok, that's quite strange. It's possible somehow that somehow the screens are "clashing", do you have another TV or something you can test the laptop with?

Comment: i use my MBP with my LG 27UD88 at home connecting direct via usb-c. works perfectly fine. i am also wondering if its due to some interference.

Comment: Strange. I'll do some research into this